# /give with ench NBT tag doesn't work 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want an iron pickaxe with Silk Touch 1. I did this:

```
/give myNameHere minecraft:iron_pickaxe 1 0 {ench:[{id:33},{lvl:1}]}
```

However, it gives me an iron pickaxe that says "Silk Touch.enchantment.level.0" and "Protection 1" below that. The Silk Touch doesn't work, and I don't know why it gave me protection (is it because I only put one series of id+lvl?). Why is this? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

`id` and `lvl` should be in the same compound tag:

```
/give @p iron_pickaxe 1 0 {ench:[{id:33,lvl:1}]}
```